# Read()/write() POSIX

Tags: c, posix, файлы

Допустим в текстовом файле имеется строка:

> abfdc 35 fd 3

после смещения с конца файла на

```
sizeof(int)
```

и выполнения команды

```
read(*file,buf,sizeof(int));
```

в буфер запишется только 3ка? или количество симбволов соответствующих sizeof()?

и елси предварительно записать содержимое буфера с помощью

```
write(*file,buf,sizeof(int))
```

и повторить lseek и read, то считается именно то что было записано, или большее число данных(если размер того, что было записано, меньше чем sizeof())?

вроде как вопрос достаточно простой, но я запутался. помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда

```
read(*file,buf,sizeof(int));
```

прочитает скорее всего 4 байта (скорее всего, на некоторых очень старых платформах int имеет длину 2 байта). И это будет 'fd 3', которые будут переведены в соответствующий тип (если buf - это int, то там будет 857760870). Но может такое быть, что символы у Вас двухбайтовые или 4 байтовые, тогда соответственно будет немного по другому (прочитается два или один символ соответственно). А может быть там нормальный utf-8,  в этом случае прочитаются 4 симовола, но если будут буквы кириллицы, то только две, так как они занимают 2 байта.

Если же запись сделать с помощью `write(*file,buf,sizeof(int))`и потом отмотать `sizeof(int)` байт назад и прочитать с помощью `read(*file,buf,sizeof(int));`, то должно прочитаться ровно то, что было записано. (при условии, что buf - это int или sizeof(buf) == sizeof(int)).

Comment: @KoVadim, IMHO вот это

     (при условии, что buf - это int или sizeof(buf) == sizeof(int)).

никак на работу read()/write() не влияет.

Прототипы функций

     ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
     ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);

Comment: т.е. записав через write число 32(int) с размером sizeof(int) и потом считав, предварительно отмотав назад на sizeof() с тем же размером, получим записанные 32?

Comment: @avp на работу то оно не влияет. А вот на результат - ещё как.

@Frnk да, если все сделаете правильно. (ну или если диск не скажет "пока"). Но кто Вам мешает сделать тестовый пример, попробовать. И, очень сильно Вам поможет [hex редактор](http://www.hexedit.com/hex-edit-shots.htm) (или берите любой другой).

Comment: @Frnk, можете попробовать.


    int file = open("xaxa", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (file == -1) {
       perror("xaxa"); exit(1);
    }
    int n = 32, m = 0;
    int l = write(file, &n, sizeof(int));
    lseek(file, -l, SEEK_CUR);
    if (read(file, &m, sizeof(int)) != l) {
       perror("read"); exit(2);
    }
    printf ("%s\n", n == m ? "Yes" : "No");
    
А какие инклюды нужны, сами в ман-ах посмотрите.

--

@KoVadim, про влияние на результат (записали 4 байта, отмотали и прочли их же) поподробнее, если можно.

Comment: @avp Вы запутали себя и меня. Говоря слово "влияет", я имел ввиду первый вариант, где @Frnk читает с текстового файла готовые данные. 
Там как раз размер int имеет значение и влияет на результат (что я подробно и описал). А вот когда пишем и читает парной командой (то есть с правильными параметрами), то размер int естественно никак на результат не влияет **кроме одного случая** -  когда пишем на одной платформе, а читаем на другой, где порядок байтов различен. Хотя это немного косвенно.

Comment: Да, для переносимости лучше работать с текстом.

С двоичными данными можно приманять htonl/ntohl/htons/ntohs, но все равно возникают проблемы с long long и double.